# Integral of $e^{\sin\frac{x}{5}}$

Tags: integration

A friend asked me how to solve this, and nothing I came up with worked.

I tried using integration by parts but ended up with $0=0$. I'm at a loss on how to integrate this.

Edit: The question he was given was this: "given $dP/dt = 5e^{\sin(t/5)}$ where $0 < t \leq 31$, find $P$ when $t=31$ given that $P = 1000$ when $t=0$."  Don't you have to find the original equation using separation of variables? Also, I would like to know how to derive the function even if it's not using elementary functions if that's possible.

Comment: That function doesn't seem to have an _elementary antiderivative_. Are you sure your friend is supposed to be able to find one manually...?

Comment: The fact that OP has written that he attempted to solve via integration by parts suggests to me that the integral he (or she) is attempting to calculate is

$$I = \int e^x \sin\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\ dx$$

Could OP confirm?

Comment: know you the Rish algorithm?

Comment: Wolfram alpha says :"No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions"

Comment: No, it is definitely e^sin(t/5) as in e raised to the power of sin(t/5)

Comment: could you use Taylor Series as an approximation?

Comment: So we want $P(31)$ :
$$
1000 + \int_0^{31} 5e^{\sin(t/5)}\ dt = 1000 + P(31) - P(0) = P(31) 
$$
But as said, this cannot be computed exactly. We have that $P(31) \approx 1000 + 196.87$